# How to initialize multiple RestAssured url in the same project without overriding each other?

Tags: rest-assured

I have multiple modules within same project which needs to communicate with entirely 2 different REST API systems. I want to use Rest Assured for both. The problem I am facing here is if I use the code for setting the baseuri (RestAssured.baseURI) it will override the previous baseURI. I tried to search how people have managed this situation. For single uri I use below:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = properties.getProperty("baseURI");
```

with the static import of RestAssured, but if I have two it overwrites the first one. Any suggestion?
I didn't want to use requestspecbuilder itself to do it as below:

```
RequestSpecBuilder requestSpecBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        requestSpecBuilder.setAccept(ContentType.JSON);
        requestSpecBuilder.setContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        requestSpecBuilder.baseUri = url;
```

as I would need to do it everytime I create a new specbuilder.

I am using Rest Assured 2.4.1. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should create a RequestSpecification as you indicate in your second example:

```
RequestSpecification spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri(url).build();
given().spec(spec). ..
```

The `spec` can then be reusable in all tests that uses the same base uri.